# Pass a javascript variables to multiple php files

Tags: javascript, php

I have a javascript with a latitude and longitude GPS coordinates, now I would like that this coordinates became a variable for more php files.
For example I have this :

```
function showPosition(position) {
    document.getElementById('lat').value = position.coords.latitude;
    document.getElementById('long').value = position.coords.longitude;
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
}
```

and a form to pass the previous two variables lat and long :

```
<form id="myForm" action="navi.php" method="post">
<input type='text' id= 'lat' name='lat' value=''>
<input type='text' id= 'long' name='long' value=''>

</form>
```

and I take both in navi.php with :

```
$x = $_POST['lat']; 
$y = $_POST['long'];
```

all work perfectly, but now, I would like to pass this variable in more then one file without other/any action.
How can I do? Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you are using these variables across multiple pages, would it not be better to set these as cookies? Then read the cookie data in either PHP or JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have `session_start();` at the top of your page:

```
$x = $_SESSION['x'] = $_POST['lat'];
$y = $_SESSION['y'] = $_POST['long'];
```

If you want to keep `$x` and `$y`, use

```
$x = $_SESSION['x'];
$y = $_SESSION['y'];
```

on your page. Make sure you call `session_start();` at the top of every page you are accessing the session variable (if you're not calling it already).

Docs for `$_SESSION`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

Comment: thanks for your answer, but there's a problem, my variables are in a javascript function, as you can see in the previous question, and I want to pass it in two or three php files.Could you help me?

Comment: @user3043636 You're already passing the variables to one PHP file, right? The above lets you access the vars across all PHP files.

Comment: @user3043636 Please mark a "Correct Answer" for future users.

Answer (score 0):

If the user isn't going to the page you could use ajax, this example might work if you're using jQuery however I haven't tested it.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { lat: "123", long: "321" }
})
.done(function( msg ) {
  console.log( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Look at this reference on global variables:

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php